# Convert Transparent PDF(spot color) to Transparent png(remove white background)

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, inkscape

I am using **imageMagick** to convert PDF image to png file with transparent background.Here is some code i tried to convert.Can anyone help me?

In imageMagick:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("document.pdf");
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent')); 
$image->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$image->writeImage("document.png");
```

Used Inkscape also :

```
inkscape  --export-png=document.png --export-dpi=200 -background none --without-gui document.pdf
```

Comment: What is the question? Do either work? Is your PDF transparent? If so, the move the setBackgroundColor before reading the PDF. If the PDF is not transparent, then the background needs to be a constant color and you convert that color to transparent.

Comment: @fmw42 Here is the transparent pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9mu4264zbrzzj8/remo.pdf?dl=0 and in pdf reader it looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmulp03h0geg8k2/preview.png?dl=0 .i want to convert that pdf to transparent png where the white pineapple will be transparent.

Comment: Where's the pineapple image? You want the white parts of the pineapple to become transparent? What should happen to the transparent parts of the pineapple? Where did the green suddenly come from?

Comment: The PDF is with spot color(green) and the remaining part of PDF is transparent(see preview.png). i want to convert file to png with transparent.

Comment: Imagemagick relies upon Ghostscript to process PDF files. Your PDF is CMYK according to Imagemagick with no alpha. Imagemagick does not know about spot colors. I am not sure if Ghostscript does either. I tried `convert -colorspace sRGB -background none -density 92 remo.pdf remo.png`. But that did not work. It looks correct if opened in Adobe Reader, but not in Mac Preview. So I suspect Adobe is using special features that only it can handle.

Comment: @fmw42 So any solution for converting that cmyk PDF file to png ?

Comment: Imagemagick can process CMYK PDF files. The issue is that Adobe is using spot colors, which Imagemgick does not handle via its use of Ghostscript to process PDF file. The issue seems to be the spot colors. I have tried opening your PDF with Mac Preview and it will not read it properly. The only tool that opens it properly is Adobe Reader.